# How to pullback a form

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, differential-topology

I am trying to make sense of pullbacks of forms as described in Guillemin and Pollack. If $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a smooth map and $\omega$ is a $p$-form on $Y$, we define a $p$-form $f^*\omega$ on $X$ as follows. If $f(x)=y$, then $f$ induces a derivative map $df_x:T_x(X)\rightarrow T_y(Y)$. Since $\omega(y)$ is an alternating $p$-tensor on $T_y(Y)$, we can pull it back to $T_x(X)$ using the transpose $(df_x)^*$. We then define the pullback of $\omega$ by $f$ by $f^*\omega(x)=(df_x)^*\omega[f(x)]$.

(Note: In general, we define the transpose as $A^*T(v_1,...,v_p)=T(Av_1,...,Av_p)$)

I am having trouble actually applying this definition to real examples. Guillemin and Pollack give none.

For example, if $f:(\pi/2,\pi/2)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is given by $f(t)=\sin t$ and $\omega=dx/\sqrt{1-x^2}$, then I begin as follows. We have that $df_t=f'(t)=\cos t$. Then $f^*\omega(t)=(\cos t)^*\omega$. Is this correct? How do I proceed?

Comment: Your $\omega$ is defined only when $x\neq \pm1$, so it is not a one form on $\mathbb R$, but $\mathbb R\setminus\{\pm 1\}$. Is $g = f$?

Comment: Yes, g should have been f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may help to unravel the notations, let $M,N$ be manifolds, $\omega\in\Lambda^pT^*N$ and $f\colon M\rightarrow N$ be smooth, then:
$$\forall x\in N,\forall (v_1,\ldots,v_p)\in T_xN,(f^*\omega)_x(v_1,\ldots,v_p):=\omega_{f(x)}(T_xf(v_1),\ldots,T_xf(v_p)),$$
this formula defines an element of $\Lambda^pT^*M$.

Assume that $M=(\pi/2,\pi/2)$, $N=\mathbb{R}$, $\omega:x\mapsto\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ and $f\colon t\mapsto\sin(t)$, then one has:
$$(f^*\omega)_t(v)=\omega_{f(t)}(T_tf(v))=\frac{\cos(t)v}{\sqrt{1-\sin(t)^2}}=\frac{\cos(t)v}{|\cos(t)|}=v,$$
since $T_tf\colon\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is the multiplication by $f'(t)$ and $\cos>0$ on $M$. Hence, $f^*\omega\equiv\mathrm{d}t$.

Comment: Since $\omega$ is a $1$-form, shouldn't we be pulling back to a $1$-form in $M$?

Comment: The first paragraph of my answer concerns the general case. In the second paragraph, $f^*\omega\colon t\mapsto\mathrm{d}t$ is a $1$-form on $M$, right? I have changed my $x$'s to $t$'s to be coherent with your notations.

Comment: It looks like you are pulling back $\omega$ to the function, or $0$-form, $\frac{\cos(t)}{|\cos(t)|}$

Comment: Don't forget the $v$ hiding in the formula I have written!

Comment: To be very precise probably you should write $v \frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ instead of $v$.

Comment: So all of $\frac{\cos(t)v}{|\cos(t)|}$ is our pullback, since it is a 1-tensor, and this is just the identity?

Comment: Further, I am confused about how your computation for $\omega(T_tf(v))$. Isn't this $\omega(\cos(t)v)=\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-(\cos(t)v)^2}}$?

Comment: Just unravel the definitions, in $\omega_x(v)$, $x$ is a parameter living on $M$, $v$ is a tangent vector of $M$ at $x$ and $\omega_x(v)$ is a real number, what you have written has no meaning. Read carefully the general definition of $f^*\omega$ in the first paragraph of my answer and try to follow how I apply it in the second paragraph. I don't know how to help you further, everything is written. If you still have difficulties after that, please tell me. Maybe, I can tell you that $\mathrm{d}x$ sends a tangent vector of $\mathbb{R}$ to itself.